# Recover files from old DVD-RW

Tags: data-recovery

In 2002 I burned a bunch of files - mostly .doc and .jpeg files, I think - onto a DVD-RW with a password. I probably did it on a Mac running OS 9, but I'm not sure. Could have been a Windows computer, or OS 8. Probably not OS X.

When I put the DVD into a drive connected to my Mac mini (2018), it won't mount. I used Disk Utility to try to mount it, and I get the following error message:

**Could not mount “disk6s1s2”. (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868.)**

(1) Any suggestions how I can retrieve the data? I'm willing to use terminal commands if that's the route to go.

(2) If I burned this on a Mac in 2002, what file structure/format would the disk have? Would it be FAT-32, or something else?

(3) Same question if it was burned on a Windows machine in 2002? FAT-32?

(4) I know the password. What kind of encryption would it have? AES128? Something else?

EDIT:

Using diskutil list, I get the following info:

```
/dev/disk6 (external, physical):

   #:       TYPE NAME        SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0: CD_partition_scheme    *267.1 MB   disk6

   1: Apple_partition_scheme  232.6 MB   disk6s1

   2: Apple_partition_map     1.0 KB     disk6s1s1

   3: Apple_HFS               231.6 MB   disk6s1s2
```

Comment: How old is the DVD drive? Not only do the discs get tired, the drives too. I recently had to rey recover some data from disks burned in the early 2k's. I still have three old Mac Pros, 2008,2009,2012. Only the 08's drive would still read any of them. That format, btw is similar to that of a Mac HD, should be readable. Windows won't be able to read it natively. It doesn't look encrypted.

Comment: The drive is a cheap LG at least 10-years old. But it works fine with everything else.

Comment: Yeah - all three of mine are fine with new discs & commercial disks. It was just this one set of ancient ones, perhaps just an edge case, though almost an expensively disappointing edge :\ I did rescue the data, it's now on less friable storage.

Comment: RW's deteriorate too, as they age.  The discs may be only marginally readable.

Comment: When you say "I know the password" -- the password to what? To the disk itself, or a DMG disk image file on the disk? I don't recall disks being encrypted on Classic MacOS. Older DMGs can be incompatible with modern Macs.

Comment: @benwiggy: I don't recall what method I used to encrypt the disk. I have my password hint written on the DVD, and my vague memory is that I password protected the whole disk. But I couldn't tell you how I did it.

I don't think there's an encrypted .dmg file on the DVD. If I remember correctly, the DVD would mount when inserted, and when I clicked the icon to open it it required a password. Behind the password was the file directory.